# How to get management studio 2008 express R2 to create SQL CE 4 file

Tags: versions, ssms, sql-server-ce

I'm facing issues whereby I can't open a SQLCE 4 database using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express R2 because of a version issue.  I've checked and I have both 'v3.5' and 'v4.0' versions of SQL CE in my Program Files, so perhaps my installation of Management Studio is using 3.5 instead of 4.0.  How can I force Management Studio to default to v4.0 of SQL CE?

I've tried deleting the 'v3.5' folder in my program files but this creates an error now when I try to create a new SQL CE database through management studio.

Thanks for any help folks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio (full or express version) do not support SQL Server CE 4 as of yet .... you gotta wait 'til SQL Server 2012 is out.

Or use the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) inside Visual Studio 2010 instead.

Comment: Wow, that seems crazy!?  Microsoft gives you a database version which their latest database admin tools can't administer?  How are we supposed to work with that!?  Very good to know though, thanks!

Comment: @Dan: SQL Server Compact 4 was released long **after** the 2008 R2 releases were out ....